# How do I take a list that is in 2 columns and make a tuple, put all the tuples in a list, and return that list?

Tags: python, list, tuples

My data looks formatted like this:

```
XX, 4059
TSD, 109
ETC, 3679
```

and I want to return something that looks like this:

```
[('XX', 4095), ('TSD', 109),..]
```

How do I take the 2 column list, make a tuple from each line, put all the tuples in a list, and return that list? I'm using PyCharm.

Please no dictionary.

```
def initilize_portfolio(filename):
    data = open("holdings.txt", "r")  # opens portfolio and reads it
    port_list = []
    for line in data:
        new_line = filename.readline().rstrip('\r\n')
        port_list.append(new_line)
    return(port_list.append)
```

I need to make a tuple somewhere and don't know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This snippet does what you are trying to achieve

```
port_list = []

with open("holdings.txt") as filename:
    for line in filename:
        # strip removes all leading and trailing spaces
        line = line.strip()
        # skip empty lines
        if not line:
            continue
        # use partition to split the entries
        a, _, b = line.partition(',')
        a = a.strip()
        b = int(b.strip())
        # create a tuple while appending
        port_list.append((a, b))
    
    
print(port_list)
```

You can put it inside a function and return the list instead of printing it.

Comment: Thank you so much for your input! I see how I can create the tuple while appending but could you explain the "a,_,b = line.partition(',') what does that line achieve? @tboschi

Comment: partition splits a string given the input string returning three elements: what comes before, the spearator (i.e. the input string), and what comes after. See here for example https://www.w3schools.com/python/ref_string_partition.asp

Comment: Also, I tried putting printing the list but I'm not getting the tuples printed out

Comment: Can you be more specific? What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

*If `holdings.txt` contains:*

```
XX, 4059
TSD, 109
ETC, 3679
```

#### The code:

```
def initilize_portfolio(filename):
    with open(filename, "r") as data:
        for s in data.read().splitlines():
            i, j = s.split(', ')
            yield i, int(j)
            
print(list(initilize_portfolio("holdings.txt")))
```

#### Output:

```
[('XX', 4059), ('TSD', 109), ('ETC', 3679)]
```

#### Explanation:

1. Open the `filename` to get its content. Note that it is considered a bad practice to open a file by assigning the returned value of the `open` call to a variable. Instead, use a `with` statement:

```
with open(filename, "r") as data:
```

2. `data.read()` will return the contents of `filenname` as a string in its raw from. The `str.splitlines()` method will turn that string into a list of all lines of `filename`, with the trailing `\n`s stripped off. Use a `for` loop to iterate through the lines:

```
    for s in data.read().splitlines():
```

3. The `str.split()` method will convert the string into a list, with each element of the list a substring in the string separated by a `' '`. The separator can be customized by providing the separator argument in the brackets. I used `', '`, and unpacked the resulting list of two elements into two variables:

```
        i, j = s.split(', ')
```

4. If you are only going to iterate through the `initilize_portfolio` function call, then you can use `yield` to safe efficiency:

```
        yield i, int(j)
```

5. With `yield`, you will need to convert the returned generator into a list, with the `list()` method:

```
print(list(initilize_portfolio("holdings.txt")))
```

---

So the above code is also the equivalent of

```
def initilize_portfolio(filename):
    port_list = list()
    with open(filename, "r") as data:
        for s in data.read().splitlines():
            i, j = s.split(', ')
            port_list.append((i, int(j)))
    return port_list

print(initilize_portfolio("holdings.txt"))
```

Comment: thanks for your input. I was having trouble adding my .txt file and making the tuple. the holdings.txt file has a number of other data in it. How can the that same concept be applied with a data file that has multiple lines?